# ID cards in Wallet app

Tags: iphone, ios

On the iOS 12 page on the Apple website, it says that you can add ID cards, however, in the app, I see no option to do this. I *am* running the latest iOS 12. How do I add an ID card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific feature is support for student IDs and will be available to students in participating universities. As of now three universities Duke University, the University of Alabama, and the University of Oklahoma have it available. Johns Hopkins, Santa Clara and Temple Universities will bring the capability by the end of this school year.

https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/10/apple-adds-support-for-contactless-student-id-cards-in-wallet/

Instructions on how to use this feature if you are a student at one of the universities that has it available can be found here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208965